# Empty session after setting data

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm doing a simple API with Laravel and I'm having issues when trying to save data into de session variable.

When a user tries to login the application I have my `LoginController` which has the following function:

```
public function postAction (Request $request) {
    ...
    $request->session()->put('user', 'helloooooo');
    ...
}
```

After that, when this user tries to get some information about their profile, I have a `middleware` called `VerifyUser` to check if his session is set:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{

    if (session('user') != null) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = 'KO';
    $response['code'] = 401;
    $response['user'] = $request->session()->all();
    return response()->json($response, 401);
}
```

I set the `user` field to `$request->session()->all();` to see what I have in the session.

But I always have a 401 response in my frontend and the session is always with this value:

> code: 401 ​​ status: "KO" ​​ user: {…} ​​​
>   _token: "9tesUdneGlK1w9685jhaWYatEKSpcFJkKyJQNnjQ"

Here are my `middlewares`:

```
protected $middleware = [
        CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        ValidatePostSize::class,
        TrimStrings::class,
        ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        TrustProxies::class,
        StartSession::class,
        QueryExceptionHandler::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            EncryptCookies::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            AuthenticateSession::class,
            ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],

        'web-out' => [
            Authorization::class,
        ],

        'web-in' => [

            VerifyUser::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Here is my `web.php` file:

```
...
Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@postAction')->middleware('web-out');
Route::get('/perfil', 'PerfilController@getAction')->middleware('web-in');

...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also post the route to the user profile data and where that is located?

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping it would be something easy like you were using the `api` middleware instead of `web`.  Is there a reason you switch from using the `Request` session to the global session helper `session('user')`?  For consistency, I would think it should be `$request->session()->get('user')`.  I don't know if this will make a difference, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried with global session helper and it doesn't work :(. I'm using Laravel to do an API and I have all the frontend in Angular. Maybe it would be the problem? Maybe the session only works when you are using Laravel to render html instead of using it like an API? @matticustard

Comment: But according to your initial post (in the yellow box), your dump shows the session user variable is being reported in the response, correct?  You put user: {...}, so I assume you are in fact seeing a stored user in the session.  Am I wrong?

Comment: What if you change `if (session('user') != null)` to `if ($request->session()->has('user'))`?